# injecting a map with multiple strings as key in a bean

Tags: spring

We can inject a bean in spring as below:

```
<bean id="injectCollection" class="CollectionInjection">
    <property name="map">
        <map>
            <entry key="someValue">
                <value>Hello World!</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="someBean">
                <ref local="oracle"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How do I inject if my key is a composite key consisting of two strings ?
How will it show in the properties file ?

Comment: What do you mean in a properties file? This map will be serialized into a properties file? And what do you mean two Strings, a list of 2 string can be your key?

Comment: @Tomer: I want to inject a map Map<List<String>, String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only map, we can inject a list also with multiple strings/classes as key in a bean

```
<bean id="injectCollection" class="CollectionInjection">
    <property name="fruits">
        <list>
            <ref bean="apple" />
            <ref bean="banana" />  
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways make this happened.
Although using a List as a key, doesn't sound good to me at all, I hope you have a very specific requirement for this.

Well, 
This is one way,

```
<bean id="myBean" class="spring.beans.MapWrapper">
    <property name="map">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <list>
                        <value>keyA</value>
                        <value>keyB</value>
                    </list>
                </key>  
                <value>value1</value>
            </entry>
        </map> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

In this example, you have a bean with a list as a key.
The list is combined of "keyA", and "keyB".
And the value of the key will be "value1".